# How to get strongly typed type from Object

Tags: dart

Can I get strongly typed value from an `Object`, something like this:

```dart
Object obj;
final fooOrBar = obj as (flag ? Foo : Bar); // Error
```

`fooOrBar` should be either of type `Foo` or `Bar` but this gives me an error.

---

**Note:**

I don't want to do things like:

```dart
if (flag) {
  final foo = obj as Foo;
} else {
  final bar = obj as Bar;
}
```

Comment: You cannot.  Since Dart does not support union types, `fooOrBar` cannot have a more specific *static* (known at compilation-time) type since what you want would determine it at *runtime* after checking `flag`.  What would you realistically do with `fooOrBar` afterward anyway?  How would calling methods on it work unless they're methods from a common base class?  And if `Foo` and `Bar` have a common base class (other than `Object`), then just cast to that instead.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I do have a base class which both `Foo` and `Bar` extends and this is what I'm currently using. But I thought instead of using the base class, can I also downcast `Object` (I mean I thought there may be some way of doing it which I wasn't aware of), that's why I asked the question. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you are asking for.

A variable has one type, determined at compile-time.
Since `flag` is not known at compile-time, it cannot affect the type of the variable `fooOrBar`.

You also cannot abstract over types like that. The thing after `as` must be a single type.
You can do

```dart
var fooOrBar = flag ? obj as Foo : obj as Bar;
```

but the static type of `fooOrBar` will likely be `Object` anyway, or at least some common supertype of `Foo` and `Bar`. Then you might as well just cast directly to that: `var castObj = obj as CommonSupertypeOfFooAndBar;`.

You can use helper functions:

```dart
Foo asFoo(Object o) => o as Foo;
Bar asBar(Object o) => o as Bar;
//...
  var fooOrBar = (flag ? asFoo : asBar)(obj);
```

Again, the type won't be `Foo` or `Bar`, but some supertype of both.

If you actually *care* about the type of `fooOrBar` being either precisely `Foo` or precisely `Bar`, you need two different variables.